# GitHub Authentication Fails

Tags: authentication, github

I just created a new repo and setup the remote link to my repo on gitbash on windows 10.
When I try to do a basic git push (git push origin main) from git bash:
I get a popup windows for username and password.
I don’t get the username and password prompt on the Git bash shell, as documentation shows me to expect.
Instead it give me a popup that asks for the userid and password.
When I enter the userid and password it fails to authenticate.
But gives me an authentication failed (invalid username or password).
But shows the url to the repo correctly (that I setup)
Even though I can use the same userid and password to login to GitHub web portal.
I don’t 2FA setup.
What am I missing?

I only found help docs relating to authentication via Windows Desktop App. Which is not very helpful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the url.
Previously I used this url: `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME.git`
Then I solved it by using this one: `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME.git`
This is very useful because it saves you from having to identify yourself each time.
Before pushing your code, I remind you to add the url using the command:
`$ git remote add origin YOURURL`
or if you added the wrong one and want to change it then use the command:
`$ git config remote.origin.url YOURURL`

After this, you can simply push your code with the following command:
`$ git push -u origin main`